# Alternative of Dynamic Keyword in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any alternative solution for dynamic keyword as I want to convert below code to c# 3.5.

```
public static dynamic ChangeTo(dynamic source, Type dest)
{
    return System.Convert.ChangeType(source, dest);
}
```

Comment: The dynamic feature took several person years to design, implement and test. If there were an easy way to get dynamic semantics without that work, we would have used it!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can just replace `dynamic` with `Object` because `dynamic` is essentially nothing more than `Object` but this will break almost all expressions involving members. It really depends on the code if this could work or will become a nightmare, i.e. if `dynamic` is used as intended it will become a nightmare.

Comment: If this is the whole method, I don't see how changing `dynamic` to `object` will break anything.

Comment: Of course, if this is the only method then all is fine. I assumed the OP wants to port more than just this method because this method is quite useless anyway just wrapping a singe static method call in a static method. I would just replace all `ChangeTo` calls directly with `Convert.ChangeType` calls unless there are really good reasons not to do that.